# Add a copyright notice to all files in a directory using Ant

Tags: ant

I want to add a copyright notice to a series of files generated in an Ant build. What's the easiest way to do it?

I thought about using `<concat>` but I don't understand how to run it on a fileset without concatenating all the files in the fileset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like `<concatfilter>` may be your friend.

```
<echo message="/* Copyright text */${line.separator}" file="copyright.txt"/>

<copy todir="dest_dir">
  <fileset dir="src_dir"/>
  <filterchain>
    <concatfilter prepend="copyright.txt"/>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
```

Comment: This looks like a nice solution. I'll try it out!

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to selectively add the copyright then you can use a copy command that replaces @COPYRIGHT@ tokens within the files.

```
  <copy todir="../backup/dir">
    <fileset dir="src_dir"/>
    <filterset>
      <filter token="COPYRIGHT" value="This text is my copyright!"/>
    </filterset>
  </copy>
```

Comment: The problem is that my code is in javascript and compressors remove all comments, so I can't use tokens :(

Comment: Isn't a copyright notice a form of comment? Sorry I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve

Comment: Javascript minifiers remove all comments, so they are removing the copyright notice from my files. I want to add it again after the minification process.

Comment: Now I understand. In that case Alexander's answer is the best solution. 

If you want more control over which files are modified checkout the fileset selector documentation: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html

Answer (score 1):

One option that wasn't mentioned so far was writing a custom Ant Task in Java. I realized there are many more factors to consider than just pre-pending a license to a file after starting my own work on a custom task which has more requirements than 'concat' can handle. Some of the scenarios and rules I had to consider:

1. Every file that is going to be distributed should contain 1 and only 1 copy of the license.
2. Does the current file have a license?
3. Does the current file have the current license?
4. If the file starts with a comment, is it a license, and it is current?
5. Is this a file that requires the license? (Don't want to write text into a binary file, or a file that won't be distributed.)

It's still a work in progress, so I don't necessarily have any code to share, but maybe the idea can help point you in the right direction if your requirements are more than out-of-the-box ant can handle, and you don't want to use antcontrib.

If you are using or considering maven, then now is the time to make the switch. You can drive ant builds from a pom.xml as well as doing any file pre-processing before building. Check out the mycila plugin which works right out of the box.

[Writing your own ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html#writingowntask)

[Maven in 5 minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

[Link to Mycila Maven plugin](http://code.mycila.com/license-maven-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use `<concat>` but within an [antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net) [`<foreach>`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) task.

Comment: @fritzfromlondon: In what way?

Comment: It tries to turn XML into a programming language which it isn't suited to. It creates a mess of if/then/loops which becomes easily unmaintanable. If one wants to write a script, just use a scripting language and call it with apply/exec, or write a custom ant task. That's my opinion of course, but I always recommend against it, and I am not the only one.

Comment: @fritzfromlondon: It depends what you're doing. It can be overkill, but it can be simple enough if used in moderation.

Comment: Agree with both .. in moderation.. sometimes you just need ANT-contrib to make life easy.. but overdoing can land you in a looping nightmare